# Is there a way to get a stack trace from rspec when a method is unexpectedly called more times than specified?

Tags: ruby, rspec, trace, expectations

I setup a mock object and told it to expect a check for nil and to return false:

```
status = double('status')
status.should_receive(:nil?).and_return(false)
```

I only expect the call to nil? to occur once, but I got an error in my rspec test, saying that status received nil? twice.

Is there a way to get rspec to show where/how each call occurred?

adding the '--backtrace' option did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
status.should_receive(:nil?).twice { puts caller; false }
```

This tells rspec to allow two invocations and call the associated block each time.  The`caller` method generates a full backtrace which you should be able to analyze on`stdout`.  We also return`false` to stay on the code-path we're testing.

If the two backtraces are hard to distinguish and you're only interested in the second (unexpected) invocation, then set up two successive expectations:

```
status.should_receive(:nil?).and_return(false)
status.should_receive(:nil?) { puts caller; false }
```

Here the double will return false on the first invocation and call the block on the second.

*Reference for setting responses on expectations:*
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#setting-responses